# Read data stored in the blocks in Ganache

Tags: blockchain, block, ethereum, ganache

Consider this is my simple smart contract.

```
uint public value;

function inputData(uint _value) public returns(uint){
    value=_value;
    return(value);
}
```

Now, i implement this smart contract on Ganache. Block-1 is formed on Ganache.
When i call a function [inputData(43)] then Block-2 is formed.
Again, when i call the same function [inputData(57)] then Block-3 is formed.
Now if i want to check the value of variable "value", it is 57, that is stored in block-3.

But, how can i check the value of variable "value" stored in block-2.??
I know, i can easily do this using mapping and other stuff, but i want to know how exactly data are stored in blocks and how can i read them???

Comment: The best way to read out the values is using JSON-RPC API and web3.js or web3.py contract interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

idk if you can check data on specific block but anyway you are overriding the value ..
so you can simply make a list of uint and keep pushing so you can have your full data , then the element in index 0 will be the data stored on block one and the element in index 1 will be the data stored on block 2 and so on..
idk if this is helpful ..
flutter has a package caller web3dart you can check data in specific block with it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).